# Mass assign error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, slim-lang

```
Rails 3.2
```

In my form, I have the following (using slim):

```
= form_for CustomerInfo.new :url => {:action => "create"}, :method => "post" do |f|
....
....
.actions = f.submit 'Save'
```

This is generating the following error:

```
Can't mass-assign protected attributes: url, method
```

In my routes.rb, I have:

```
post '/customer_infos' => 'customer_infos#create', as: 'customer_info'
```

Isn't this syntax allowed under Rails  3.2?

## Solution:

I solved it by doing:

```
= form_fo(CustomerInfo.new :url customer_info_path) do |f|
```

Comment: If you have a solution, please post it as an answer. Answer don't belong in the question. You can self-answer your question it a good pratice on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

Try

customer_infos controller:

```
def new
 @customer_info = CustomerInfo.new()
end
```

Form:

```
form_for(@customer_info) do |f|
  ....
  ....
f.submit
```